# how to prevent a product be added to a cart?

Tags: event-observer, magento-1, addtocart

**For certain reason, i have to prevent the users to add the product into the cart.**

here is the event in `config.xml`

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
        <observers>
            <abc_findp>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>Abc_Findp_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>searchStock</method>
            </abc_findp>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
</events>
```

**Observer:**

```
public function searchStock($observer) {

    //how to prevent a product be added to a cart?
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('This product can't be added to shopping cart.');



}
```

Or i need to use checkout_cart_product_add_after event, to remove the quote item after added into a cart?

Thanks.!

Comment: just remove cart button simple

Comment: Or set as out of stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is so funny method to solve the problem.

change to use `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and use in observer method

```
public function removeMessage ($observer) {
    $observer->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
}
```

this will prevent the product to be added into the cart and avoid the success message

Comment: Sometimes I don't have the method _getSession in the observer.